# Ordenar archivo de texto

Tags: python, bucle-for, txt

Tengo un archivo de texto con el libro del Quijote, mi objetivo es tomar el libro quitar los saltos de línea y hacer un split en los (puntos) (comas) y (puntos y comas) de modo que obtenga una lista con todas las oraciones del libro. ejemplo

```
Yo, Juan Gallo de Andrada, escribano de Cámara del Rey nuestro señor, de
los que residen en su Consejo, certifico y doy fe que, habiendo visto por
los señores dél un libro intitulado El ingenioso hidalgo de la Mancha,
compuesto por Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, tasaron cada pliego del dicho
libro a tres maravedís y medio; el cual tiene ochenta y tres pliegos, que
al dicho precio monta el dicho libro docientos y noventa maravedís y medio,
en que se ha de vender en papel; y dieron licencia para que a este precio
se pueda vender, y mandaron que esta tasa se ponga al principio del dicho
libro, y no se pueda vender sin ella. Y, para que dello conste, di la
presente en Valladolid, a veinte días del mes de deciembre de mil y
seiscientos y cuatro años.
```

Ejemplo de como se tendria que ver

```
Yo
Juan Gallo de Andrada
escribano de Cámara del Rey nuestro señor
de los que residen en su Consejo
```

Pues bien tengo esto hecho pero no lo hace como quisiera.

```
with open(ruta_libros.format("quijote"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as libro:
    large_str=""
    for line in libro:
        large_str+=line.rstrip()
    

lista=large_str.split(".")
print(lista)
```

El libro tiene algunos caracteres que podrian ser inecesarios como estos (- «  » ... "" ) no se si realmente esto afecta el proceso, pero el libro no parece guardarse completamente con el ciclo, almenos no la primera parte.

Aquí hecha un vistazo online de como es el libro en txt, tal vez entiendas si python es incompatible con algo.
[TXT del Quijote](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2000/2000-0.txt)

```
ingo Revulgo
Estos dos príncipes, sin que los solicite adulación mía ni otro género de aplauso, por sola su bondad, han tomado a su cargo el hacerme merced y favorecerme
en lo que me tengo por más dichoso y más rico que si la fortuna por camino ordinario me hubiera puesto en su cumbre
La honra puédela tener el pobre, pero no el vicioso
```

Esto es una parte de lo que hay encima de ingo Revulgo, lo cual parece que Mingo se corta.(esta no es lo que se imprime sino parte de lo que no se procesa)

```
Dile también que de la amenaza que me hace, que me ha de quitar la ganancia
con su libro, no se me da un ardite, que, acomodándome al entremés famoso
de La Perendenga, le respondo que me viva el Veinte y cuatro, mi señor, y
Cristo con todos. Viva el gran conde de Lemos, cuya cristiandad y
liberalidad, bien conocida, contra todos los golpes de mi corta fortuna me
tiene en pie, y vívame la suma caridad del ilustrísimo de Toledo, don
Bernardo de Sandoval y Rojas, y siquiera no haya emprentas en el mundo, y
siquiera se impriman contra mí más libros que tienen letras las Coplas de
Mingo Revulgo.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dado que el texto es largo, es conveniente procesarlo por partes. En este caso, elegimos procesar en párrafos, a fin de no cortar las oraciones que abarcan más de una línea.

El fin del párrafo se reconoce al encontrar una línea vacía. Cuando es fin de párrafo, pasamos la lista de líneas acumuladas a un función que la procesara. Si no es fin de párrafo, la línea se acumula en la lista `parrafo`.

```
with open("quijote.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as libro:
    parrafo = []
    for line in libro:
        line = line.strip()   # Botar los whitespaces al final.
        if line == '':
            for oracion in procesar_parrafo(parrafo):
                print(oracion)
            parrafo = []
        else:
            parrafo.append(line)
```

El proceso de dividir el párrafo por separados se haría apropiadamente usando expresiones regulares. No las usare para hacer más simple el código.

La función recibe una lista de lineas. Lo primero es armar una sola línea usando `join`.

No tenemos una función `split` que divida por varios separadores a la vez. Lo que hare será reemplazar los ";" y "," con "." (usando `replace`), para luego hacer `split(".")` y devolver la lista de oraciones.

El paso final, en el `return`, es eliminar los whitespaces al principio y al final de cada oración usando compresión de listas.

```
def procesar_parrafo(parrafo):

    completo = ' '.join(parrafo)
    completo = completo.replace(",", ".")
    completo = completo.replace(";", ".")
    lista_punto = completo.split(".")

    return [x.strip() for x in lista_punto]
```

produce:

```
El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha
TASA
Yo
Juan Gallo de Andrada
escribano de Cámara del Rey nuestro señor
de los que residen en su Consejo
certifico y doy fe que
habiendo visto por los señores dél un libro intitulado El ingenioso hidalgo de la Mancha
compuesto por Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra
tasaron cada pliego del dicho libro a tres maravedís y medio
el cual tiene ochenta y tres pliegos
que al dicho precio monta el dicho libro docientos y noventa maravedís y medio
en que se ha de vender en papel
y dieron licencia para que a este precio se pueda vender
y mandaron que esta tasa se ponga al principio del dicho libro
y no se pueda vender sin ella
```

Comment: Wao no estaba ni 5% cerca, ya analice el codigo y como funciona, es magnifico, sin embargo, me gustaria saber si probaste con el libro completo, resulta que cuando se imprimen las oraciones lo hace empezando muy a bajo y no al principio como se ve en tu ejemplo, no se si sea porque la consola no aguanta imprimir tanto, ¿porque sera que no se visualiza gran parte del principio?

Comment: Empiezo a obtener los resultados desde casi la mitad del texto, observa mi pregunta para que veas como y por donde empieza.

Comment: @lolita La consola no tiene capacidad para retener todo el texto procesado. Por eso sólo te muestra las últimas líneas. Ejecuta redirigiendo la salida estandar a un archivo y veras que sale completo. Tambien puedes expandir el código y grabar a un archivo en lugar de hacer print.

Comment: @lolita. Si, probe el libro completo.

Comment: A bueno, que alivio, pues entonces este tema esta cerrado, muchas gracias Moe.

Comment: @lolita. No tienes que confiarte. Siempre chequea el código, tuyo o de otros.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119563/discussion-between-lolita-and-candid-moe).